# Asp.Net MVC 3: If Controllers instantiate for each user, why is Session ID null in a constructor function?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, controller

I'm trying to reuse a SessionID from a cookie or generate a new cookie otherwise.  I thought I could add this to the controller constructor function so all Action Methods would know what SessionID to use.  However, the constructor's Session object is null.

Would I have to decorate every Action Method entry point with code to check for an existing SessionID cookie?

Comment: SessionID from a Cookie? Is this for authentication? The idea is to decorate your action methods with the `Authorize` attribute, then that will go and get it for you. Or if you just want the current user Id, just to `HttpContext.User.Identity.AccountName`

Comment: `Authorize` though forces them to be logged in, which is their opportunity, but I don't want to force it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The constructor is too early in the Controller lifecycle - it doesn't know about Session yet. Override [`Initialize()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.initialize.aspx) instead.